# Sending latitude and longitude to server from android app

Tags: php, android, google-maps

I tried sending latitude and longitude using the following code

```
package com.example.john.bustrackgps;

import android.Manifest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String mprovider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        mprovider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if (mprovider != null && !mprovider.equals("")) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mprovider);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mprovider, 15000, 1, this);

            if (location != null)
                onLocationChanged(location);
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location Provider Found Check Your Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        longitude.setText("Current Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
        latitude.setText("Current Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if (success) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServerUpload.class);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Upload failed")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };


        ServerUpload registerRequest = new ServerUpload(latitude,longitude,responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        queue.add(registerRequest);

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s,int i,Bundle bundle)
    {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s)
    {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s)
    {}
}
```

This is my ServerUpload class

```
package com.example.john.bustrackgps;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class ServerUpload extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.169.2/serverfiles/bts.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public ServerUpload(TextView latitude, TextView longitude, Response.Listener<String> listener){

        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);

        final String latitude1 =latitude.toString();
        final String longitude1 =longitude.toString();
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("latitude", latitude1);
        params.put("longitude", longitude1);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

This is my bts.php code

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "bustrack");


$latitude = $_POST["latitude"];

$longitude = $_POST["longitude"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO updates (latitude, longitude) VALUES (?, ?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $latitude, $longitude);

mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);


$response = array();

$response["success"] = true;  


echo json_encode($response);
```

The problem is that data does not get entered into the database. Its either 0,0 or "android.extends...."

I am very new to android and not sure were the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: First check/debug  that you are getting Lat long or not, Then try to check that data is passed to server properly  or not?? And after that check your PHP code for database.

Comment: Yes i am getting latitude and longitude properly. They get displayed. The problem happens at data passing to server.

Comment: I think your question is not clear have getting problem on server or android side code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix this bug in your `ServerUpload` method .

```
 final String latitude1 =latitude.getText().toString();
final String longitude1 =longitude.getText().toString();
```

Try this

```
 public ServerUpload(TextView latitude, TextView longitude, Response.Listener<String> listener){

    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);

    final String latitude1 =latitude.getText().toString();
    final String longitude1 =longitude.getText().toString();
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("latitude", latitude1);
    params.put("longitude", longitude1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It does get uploaded now. However the app crashes immediately after updating to the server. And the latitude and longitude gets inserted twice. Could you help me with that as well please? Note: It used to crash before as well. I don't know why though...

Comment: @John ask another question with your stack traces and code.